# What does it mean when variables in in (probability) weighted regression are significant but variables in an unweighted regression are not?

Tags: r, regression, weights, weighted-regression

I'm running to regressions. One with probability weights inputted and another one without. When running them, my results indicate that some unadjusted variables are insignificant, but those same variables are significant when weights are inputted. How do I interpret this?

Comment: What do you mean by "regression with/without weights"? What tool are you using? How do the results "indicate" significance?

Comment: I mean probability weights. I'm running a glm. The P value.

Comment: Could you post the two glm models you are using? And the summaries?